# The remote name could not be resolved: 'your_uri'

Tags: episerver, episerver-find

I am trying to do some querying operations in episerver CMS...while doing i got the Above mentioned error occurred...the code i have used is,

```
        int contentTypeId = 16;
        var pages = SearchClient.Instance.Search<IContent>()
          .Filter(x => x.ContentTypeID.Match(contentTypeId))
          .GetContentResult();
```

Thanks and Regards,
Mohan.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** I would guess **'your_uri'** is a leftover from a sample configuration. Check your Episerver Find settings in **web.config** and make sure the URL and index name are correct.

Also, you should still use strongly typed content models wherever possible.

In this case use `SearchClient.Instance.Search<YourContentType>()` to search for a specific content type.

Comment: i am new to episerver...so could you give me any example for this?

Comment: LMGTFY :) https://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/EPiServer-Find/9/DotNET-Client-API/Searching/Filtering/Filtering/